# Excel links and macros are not working in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online

We recently migrated file server data to SharePoint online. After migrating, excel links and macros are not working. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to work with these excel files (with macros) **in Client Application** not in Online Application.

Answer (score 0):

Excel Online doesn't support macros:

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Work-with-macros-in-Excel-Online-98784ad0-898c-43aa-a1da-4f0fb5014343